# Regular expressions in OData $filter conditions?

Tags: regex, odata

I am considering offering an `OData` interface to my database. I need to allow regular expressions on string fields, i.e., in `OData $filter` conditions.

OData offers `substringof()`, `startswith()`, and other functions, but I could not find anything about regular expressions in the docs. 
Is this possible?

Such a regex function would probably look like:

```
/Customers?$filter=match(CompanyName, '^Al[a-z]+s Futterkiste') eq true
```

where `match()` is a function that I just made up.

Answer (score 1):

The protocol doesn´t have any built-in regex operator for filtering. However you can achieve what you are looking for (or something similar) as follow:

```
GET http://server/Customers?$filter=match(CompanyName=$it/CompanyName, Regex='^Al[a-z]+s Futterkiste') eq true
```

In this case, you have to have a function 'match' which takes two paramentes: CompanyName and Regex. That function returns true/false depending on company name matches or not. Then, for each company, match function is invoked.

Of course the implementation depends on the server-side technology you are using.

You can read more here: http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData.html#inlineparametersyntax

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For efficiency reasons, using such an externally defined function is impossible for me (have millions of rows).

Comment: How much time does it take?